# Reading gibberish filename (FTP/FSO)

Tags: vbscript, ftp, filesystemobject, fso

Looking at my server, i see filenames, that theur characters have been messed up.
Example: `ôøùú-ô÷åãé-1.mp3`

should should be Hebrew letters.

While the files can be read in a browser and FTP, they cannot be read always - for example, in an online audio player, or VBScript FSO (File system object)

is there something that can be done to change the charset or something, so that i can read and then rename these files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, using this link: http://pastebin.com/yXRWDggY

```
            function convertChar(letter)

                lat = array("à","á","â","ã","ä","å","æ","ç","è","é","ê","ë","ì","í","î","ï","ð","ñ","ò","ó","ô","õ","ö","÷","ø","ù","ú", " " )
                heb = array("א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","ך","כ","ל","ם","מ","ן","נ","ס","ע","ף","פ","ץ","צ","ק","ר","ש","ת", " ")

                inarray = false 
                for ii = 0 to ubound(heb)
                    if letter = heb(ii) then
                        convertChar = lat(ii)
                        inarray = true 
                        exit for 
                    end if 
                next 

                if inarray = false then convertChar = letter 

            end function
```